# Edit: How to transfer array values to positive and negative arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        int n=0, d=0, temperature[20], sum, a, t;
        int positive[10], negative[10];
        float avg;

    //--------------------------------
    cout << "Number of days: ";
    cin >> n;

    for (d=0; d<n; d++)
    {
        cout << "enter " << d+1 << " day temperature: ";
        cin >> temperature[d];
    }
    for (d=0; d<n; d++)
    {
        cout << temperature[d]<<endl;

    }
    sum=0;
    for (d=0; d<n; d++) {
    sum = sum + temperature[d];
    }

    avg = sum/n;
    cout << "Average: " <<  avg;


if (temperature[d] > avg) {
positive[t] = temperature[d];
t += 1;
}
if (temperature[d] < avg) {
negative[a] = temperature[d];
a += 1;
}
if (positive[t]>negative[a])
{
cout << "positive";
}
```

So, I have some problems with my assignment.  I would like to ask how to transfer positive and negative values from array temperature to arrays positive and negative? Because it doesn't work as it is now.

Comment: `cin >> array[i];` ... where do you declare `i`?

Comment: Thank you, haven't seen this... It had to be "c" instead of "i", now it shows normal numbers that I entered, but now when I enter el_nr, when i write array numbers, I have to enter one more number, than I entered element, what could be the problem?

Comment: Change `c<=el_nr` to `c<el_nr`. Remember that c++ uses 0 based indexing.

Comment: Maybe you can help with edited code that i added?

Comment: `int positive[], negative[];` are errors; array sizes must be constants.

Comment: Yeah I know, edited code, but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

```
cout << " Enter array numbers \n";
for (c=0; c<=el_nr; c++) {
cin >> array[i];
}
```

should be

```
cout << " Enter array numbers \n";
for (c=0; c<el_nr; c++) {
cin >> array[c];
}
```